# How to query all records from a model matching two or more values in Django Model using SQLite

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I have this query inside one of my `views.py`. My query needs to search for football matches in all the leagues specified in my query value. In addition, I would like to get all upcoming matches by selecting all matches with `kickoff_date`, say, five days from now.

```
 topgames =Predictions.objects.filter(league='Epl' or 'Bundesliga' or 'Liga BBVA' or 'The 
 Championship',kickoff_date= // I want to fiter the kickoff_date  based on a time range ie. (5 days from now) // )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly figured it out

```
  topgames =Predictions.objects.filter(league__in=['Epl','Bundesliga','Liga BBVA','The Championship'],
            kickoff_date__range=(date.today(), date.today() +timedelta(days=7)))
```